# How to change the color of text in an image?

Tags: html, css

I have implemented an animation of text that moves in a circle. The picture is in the center. When the text runs over the image, the color of the text should change. How can I implement the data effect?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY0PD.png)

Comment: Have a look at mix-blend-mode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: See [ask] and edit your question to include a [mcve]